# Binding ComboBox with collection of integers

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Exact same code works fine with collection of strings, yet it fails with integer.

My code (removed unnecessary parts to make things clear):

XAML:

```xml
        <ComboBox Name="Id" 
                  Grid.Row="5"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Id}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Ids}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}"
                  IsEnabled="True"
                  IsEditable="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
    class ViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<int> Ids { get; set; }

        new public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

```cs
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

(Code and names have been adjusted to represent the issue while ignoring unnecessary informations)

List has been populated, i can select one of the options, but chosen option is blank, empty. User can't tell what has been selected. Any suggestions what is wrong here?

Edit

Parsing each integer to string (and changing collection to string) fixes the issue. I don't know, it appears that ComboBox doesn't like integers.

Comment: Please post the full class definition for your ViewModel, including the Id property that you're trying to bind against

Comment: Where and how is your `Id` property defined?

Comment: Ah, i forgot about showing base view model. Id is defined.

Comment: You only need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged once - in your BaseViewModel class, not in every ViewModel class

Comment: Also, your property setters do not fire the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: @Peregrine praise Fody, he does it for me.

Comment: you still have conflicting PropertyChanged events though

Comment: Well, it works fine with it, so i'm keeping it. "if it isn't broke don't fix it". I'm not saying you are wrong, i just don't want to break anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is, that your ComboBox has the Name "Id" and you want to bind to a property with the same name. If you don't use the name of the ComboBox I would suggest removing it. Otherwise you can rename it.

Edit: Of course your viewmodel must contain the "Id"-property:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Ids { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Removing name changed nothing. Results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you removed some of the other code, you could create a new class in the same namespace of 'class ViewModel' with an ID property of type int and use that class as the type for your ObservableCollection.  Then in your ComboBox, set the SelectedValuePath to ID and bind SelectedValue back to the Id property that's in the BaseViewModel class.

Lastly, you should be able to remove the reference to INotifyPropertyChanged in 'class ViewModel' because this should be automatically inherited when using BaseViewModel as the base class.

Something like this...

**C#**:

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
     public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxIDClass> Ids { get; set; }
}

public class ComboBoxIDClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public int ID { get; set; }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<ComboBox Name="Id" Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Ids}" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Id}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}" IsEnabled="True" IsEditable="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the binding mode to TwoWay:

```
<ComboBox Name="Id" 
              Grid.Row="5"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Ids}" 
              Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}"
              IsEnabled="True"
              IsEditable="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"/>
```